# pd.to_csv adding sep info as metadata to csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, file

I have a basic code for saving a dataframe as .csv file with a semicolon separator, following:

```
df.to_csv(path, sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

And it saves, like:

```
df.csv
    col1;col2;col3;col4
    val1;val2;val3;val4
```

However, when I try to open `df.csv` with the Excel program, it automatically separates the columns with commas (,) -not semicolons- as it results in incorrect separation. The solution I found is to add sep info to the file inside the first row:

```
df.csv
    sep=;
    col1;col2;col3;col4
    val1;val2;val3;val4
```

Of course, doing it with an extra file writing operation is possible. However, I am looking to see if there is a more pythonic way or specific parameter that I can set to make it automatically include meta info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excel is IMO terrible with csv files. Instead of opening the csv file, *import* it, specifying `;` as the delimiter.

Comment: I totally agree. However, it is used widely in the company. So it has to be compatible with excel, no other. This method could have been possible if columns wouldn't be separated with commas automatically when you open the file.

Comment: What is the reason for using a `;` separator if you later want to process the csv file using an Excel environment requiring `,`? Said differently what prevents you from using directly `df.to_csv(path, sep=',', ...)`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for the good question. Values (strings) on some columns have commas and they should stay in the same column. Therefore, using commas as separator makes them separated as well which is what I don't want.

Comment: No. The CSV specification says that *character* fields can be enclosed in quote marks (default `"`), to allow them to contain separator characters or even new lines. And both Pandas and the csv module from the standard library can handle that, and handles it *by default*. And Excel (despite having a awful csv file processing...) will be glad with such a file.

Comment: I see. However, changing the sep character is not possible since it is a standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most pythonic might be to just read the first line, then read again the file:

```
with open('df.csv') as f:
    sep = f.readline().strip().split('=')[-1]
    print(f'separator: {sep}')
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', skiprows=1, sep=sep)
print(df)
```

If you really want to open the file only once you can use `io.StringIO`, but I suspect this might be less efficient:

```
import io

with open('df.csv') as f:
    sep = f.readline().strip().split('=')[-1]
    print(f'separator: {sep}')
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(f.read()), sep=sep)
print(df)
```

output:

```
separator: ;
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  val1  val2  val3  val4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess my question was misunderstood. I am actually asking how I can insert a sep info to the file, not how I can read it. I have added more information.